# Professor doesn't tell TAs what should be on exams until the day of the exam

Tags: teaching-assistant

As a TA I am responsible for preparing problems and solution sets for the exams.  Last time we had an exam, the professor didn't tell us which problems he wanted to select for the exam until the morning of the exam, which meant I had to write solutions for a large number of problems the night before the exam, most of which did not end up being on the exam.  Now there is another exam coming up and I fear I will have to do this again.  What should I do?

Comment: Talk to him...?

Comment: Do you mean that you don't know what's on the test and so you can't make an answer key or explanation for reviewing the test with students later, or you don't know what to put on the exam yourselves until the day of? Either way this sounds bizarre, as a TA you should not be doing work with no apparent benefit to the professor or students (terrible waste of time, it sounds like), and you'll surely need to talk with the Professor to see how you should be handling this.

Comment: @BrianDHall: The TAs have to propose problems for the exams, and the professor selects from those problems, and then I have to write the solution sets for them.  But the professor doesn't choose which problems he wants on the test until the day of the test.  Last time I actually started printing out two different copies of the test because he didn't tell us until the last minute.

Comment: @JamalS: He doesn't respond to a lot of emails, especially ones where we ask him to pick problems that should be on the test >.<

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. Why do you need to write answers for problems you're not even sure will be on the test? Shouldn't you wait till you see what the questions are?

Comment: _He doesn't respond to a lot of emails_ — And so what happened when you asked him about this in person?  You _did_ ask him about this in person, didn't you?

Comment: Your writing is not clear.  Assuming that the professor will not tell you what is on the exam, until after the exam begins, is perhaps to guarantee the integrity of the exam.  I.E., the TA can't possible tell the students, what is on the exam, prior to the exam.  I'm not challenging your integrity. This may be the department's policy (not the professor).

Comment: I don't understand why you were writing out all the answers and printing out two different copies of the test before he made the decisions. May be you should wait for him until he made the decision?

Answer (score 2):

Tell him you'd like it if either a) he gave you the problems at least  one day before the exam or b) he gave you permission to decide what would be on the exam (within reason, of course)